# SQL Server using inner join on 2 databases with different SQL authentication credentials

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

This probably can't be done, but thought I'd ask anyway.

On my SQL Server I have 2 databases, each has different SQL Authentication credentials - different usernames and passwords on each one as each are used by different programs.

What I want to do is an inner join query which links 2 tables, one from each database.

If it was Just Windows authentication, I could use something like:

```
SELECT a.userID, 
       b.usersFirstName, 
       b.usersLastName  
FROM 
       TableA a 
inner join 
       databaseB.dbo.TableB b  
ON 
       a.userID=b.userID
```

but as its SQL Authentication I can't see how to enter the credentials of the second database.

This is for use in a VB.Net program which already creates an connection to the first database (hence the missing database and schema names as they're already set in the connection string)

Can this be done?

EDIT:

To clarify - they are both on the **same** server. Each one has a **different** username and password

The two connection strings in the VB.Net program are like this:

```
Data Source=VIMES;Database=database1;User Id=username1; Password=password1

Data Source=VIMES;Database=database2;User Id=username2; Password=password2
```

Comment: Have you explored linked server feature yet? Might solve your problem

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking here. If you have 2 databases on the **same** server (which is implied here, due to the 3 part naming) then they can't have different authentication methods. Authentication method is set at server level. Sounds like you simply haven't created a user for the login on the other database.

Comment: danish - same server

Comment: Larnu - yes they can - and do!  :-) I access each database separately on the same server using different credentials. It's set at database level, not server

Comment: You need to grant access to both databases (and corresponding tables) for your software users.

Comment: Search SO for sql server linked server query

Comment: No, @Tym , they don't. You might use different methods when you connect directly to the database, but that isn't the same. A database doesn't have a security model, the server does (if a Server has mixed authentication, then **all** databases on that server can use SQL logins, or Windows Logins). I'm not even sure why you're using a different login for the 2 separate databases; is it needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to show this is with a script. This is pretty much self explanatory, however, if you have any question, please comment:

```
USE master;
GO
--Create sample Login
CREATE LOGIN SampleLogin WITH PASSWORD = 'ASD123!"£';
GO
--Create 2 test databases
CREATE DATABASE Sample1;
CREATE DATABASE Sample2;
GO

USE Sample1;
GO
--Create a user linked to the login in the first database
CREATE USER SampleUser FOR LOGIN SampleLogin;
GO
--Create a sample table
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (ID int);
INSERT INTO SampleTable 
VALUES (1),(2),(3);
GO
--Grant permissions
GRANT SELECT ON SampleTable TO SampleUser;
GO

USE Sample2;
GO
--Create a table in the other database
CREATE TABLE SampleTable (ID int, fID int);
INSERT INTO SampleTable 
VALUES (4,1),(5,2),(6,3);
GO

USE Sample1;
GO
--Change database context and execute as the sample login
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'SampleLogin';
GO
--This will fail. This is because SampleLogin doesn't have permission to access the database Sample2
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable ST1
     JOIN Sample2.dbo.SampleTable ST2 ON ST1.ID = ST2.ID;

GO
REVERT;
GO

USE Sample2
GO
--Switch to Sample2 and create a User on the database for the Login and grant permissions.
CREATE USER SampleUser FOR LOGIN SampleLogin;
GRANT SELECT ON SampleTable TO SampleUser;
GO

USE Sample1;
GO
--Let's try it again.
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = 'SampleLogin';
GO
--Success! Beacuse the SQL Login has a user on both databases
SELECT *
FROM SampleTable ST1
     JOIN Sample2.dbo.SampleTable ST2 ON ST1.ID = ST2.fID;
GO
REVERT;
GO
--Clean up
USE master;
DROP DATABASE Sample1;
DROP DATABASE Sample2;
DROP LOGIN SampleLogin;
GO
```

The problem in your current set up is that your Login only has a User on the database you're connecting to; it doesn't have one on the second. Create it a user on the second, and it'll work. You don't need 2 different logins for separate databases from the same application.

Comment: Thanks Larmu. I appreciate the work you put into this reply. As you say,  the problem is two sets of credentials. I think, as this is an in-house application, I'm going to add a user to each database so that I can connect to each with the same credentials and then use the original SQL as posted in the question. Marking yours as correct in recognition of the work you put into answering it. Many thanks.